# How to capture and store Images?

Tags: angularjs, image, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to capture images and send them to the server .

So, I used [this tutorial](https://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/):

My controller :

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

        // 4
        onImageSuccess(imageData);

        function onImageSuccess(fileURI) {
            createFileEntry(fileURI);
        }

        function createFileEntry(fileURI) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, copyFile, fail);
        }

        // 5
        function copyFile(fileEntry) {
            var name = fileEntry.fullPath.substr(fileEntry.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var newName = makeid() + name;

            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem2) {
                fileEntry.copyTo(
                    fileSystem2,
                    newName,
                    onCopySuccess,
                    fail
                );
            },
            fail);
        }
```

I get this error though:

> !JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, copyFile, fail)')

how to resolve this?

Comment: Did your code is excuted after "deviceready" event?

Comment: no ,wha't the deviceready ?

Comment: It's an event sent by cordova/phonegap to say "Ok, plugins (and other) are loaded". All you need is here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

Comment: So, in your case, your deviceready callback can be the file upload OR a bit harder, Angular Manual Bootstrap

Comment: where i can added ,in my code?

Comment: The simple way is to put around your "$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then...." function. So your "deviceready" callback will be "function(){$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then....}"

... Also, don't forget to add this line to your index.html: <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

Comment: Can you created a plunkr with your code?

Comment: look please i get this message (!JavaScript LOG: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. 
!JavaScript LOG: Channel not fired: onCordovaReady )

Comment: Can you try this solution: http://christian.fei.ninja/Solution-to-PhoneGap-issue-device-ready-has-not-fired-after-5-seconds/ . How many plugins do you have? It's seems this error is produced by too heavy application

Answer (score 1):

you need the fail function.

```
function fail(error) {
            console.log("fail: " + error.code);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to work with image galleries (Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY), when it works, change to CAMERA. After "getPicture" the images are in the cache folder (in my case "pathAppCache". It needs to copy them to your folder (in my case "pathAppImagens".

Try

```
        $scope.choosePhoto = function () {


        var options = {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            allowEdit: false,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 200,
            targetHeight: 200,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
            correctOrientation: true
        };            

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imagem) {            
            console.log("getPicture" + imagem);

            // Copy file to my imagem folder  
            $cordovaFile.copyFile(pathAppCache, "modified.jpg", pathAppImagens, "logo_empresa.jpg").then(function (success) {

                console.log("copyFile " + success);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("copyFile " + error);
            });
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("getPicture " + error);
        });

    };
```

First of all we set up the directories

```
        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            pathApp = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
            pathAppCache = cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory;
            pathAppImagens = pathApp + "imagens/";
        };                
        // Se estiver rodando na plataforma iOS
        if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            pathApp = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
            pathAppCache = cordova.file.cacheDirectory;
            pathAppImagens = pathApp + "imagens/";
        };
```

For details look here http://sourcefreeze.com/cordova-camera-plugin-example-using-ionic-framework/

Comment: what's this error please (!JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL')

Comment: Probably your attribute "FullPath" is undefined. Check what is returning in "fileEntry". But believe me, this tutorial look like confusing.

Comment: i resolved but another error is display("GOT A dragExit when dndGesture is null!")  ??

Comment: i capture a picture and is converted to string  but this picture is not display :(